# Update xml attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML similar to this

```
<list>
    <sublist id="a">
        <item name="name1">
            <property1>a</property1>
            <property2>b</property2>
        </item>
        <item name="name2">
            <property1>c</property1>
            <property2>d</property2>
        </item>
    </sublist>
    <sublist id="b">
        [...more XML here...]
    </sublist>
</list>
```

I want to modify the name attribute of an especific item. Sublist id, item name and the new item name will be passed to the function as arguments. So it will look something like this:

```
<list>
    <sublist id="a">
        <item name="****NEW NAME****">
            <property1>a</property1>
            <property2>b</property2>
        </item>
        <item name="name2">
            <property1>c</property1>
            <property2>d</property2>
        </item>
    </sublist>
    <sublist id="b">
        [...more XML here...]
    </sublist>
</list>
```

Here is the code i'm using to replace it (I didn't add the code for loading and saving the XML, passing arguments...I have them implemented)

```
[...Load XML...]
Dim attr as XmlAttribute
attr = xmlData.SelectSingleNode.("//sublist[@id='" & sublistID & "']/item[@name='" & itemName & "'")
attr.Value = newName
[...Save XML...]
```

sublistID, itemName and newName are passed as arguments to the function (as I said before). I think that I fail in the SelectSingleNode, but I don't know why.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted will not run without throwing an exception.  I suspect that the reason that you are not seeing the exception is because you have this code inside a Try/Catch block which is eating the exception and not notifying you that it happened.

The cause of the error is that you are selecting the `item` element, but you are trying to cast it to an `XmlAttribute` variable.  The cast from an `XmlElement` to and `XmlAttribute` fails and throws an exception.  To fix it, you need to select the `name` attribute rather than the `item` element, like this:

```
Dim attr As XmlAttribute = DirectCast(xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//sublist[@id='a']/item[@name='name1']/@name"), XmlAttribute)
```

The key difference is the `/@name` at the end of the XPath.  Note that I also added the `DirectCast`.  Having `DirectCast` there is necessary when you have `Option Strict On`, as you almost certainly ought to.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to respond this. It looks like this is correct. But now I'm getting a "System.Xml.XPath.XPathException", maybe because of the arguments of the XPath in SelectSingleNode

Comment: I tested it with your example and it worked fine, so there must be something else going on (probably because your real XML document is more complex than the example?).  I can't really help without more information or an example that demonstrates the issue, but I would suggest simplifying the XPath until you get it to work, then add one bit of complexity at a time, testing it each step of the way, until you get it to select exactly what you want.

Comment: My XML is more complex, I tried to simplify it so anyone could understand my problem easily. It's a music playlist, but the basic tree of nodes is the same. I will try to change the path.

Comment: This is the error I get. I checked if those elements (test, test1) exist in the Playlist, and they do. -->     System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: '//Playlist[@ID='test']/Song[@Name'test1']/@'test1'' has an invalid token.

Comment: You're missing the equal-sign in `@Name='test1'`.  Also, you probably want to select `/@Name` rather than `@test1`.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. I was tried for my purpose... you may change this based on your requirement...

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString() + "Frame.xml"))
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc1f = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc1f.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString() + "Frame.xml");
    System.Xml.XmlNode rootcomment1f = doc1f.SelectSingleNode("/FrameDetail");
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodes1f = rootcomment1f.SelectNodes("Frame");

    if (nodes1f.Count != 0)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument docff = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        docff.Load(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBCache"].ToString() + "Frame.xml");
        System.Xml.XmlNode rootcommentff = docff.SelectSingleNode("/FrameDetail");
        System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodesff = rootcommentff.SelectNodes("Frame");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodesff.Count; i++)
        {
            if (nodesff[i].SelectSingleNode("REFERENCEID").InnerText.Trim() == "2")
            {%>
                <center><div style="padding:1px;width:100%;height:100%;"><iframe src="<%=nodesff[i].SelectSingleNode("URL").InnerText%>" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="background:transparent;" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div></center>           
            <%}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example solves a different problem than the one the OP is asking about.  The OP is trying to select an attribute based on the value of an ancestor's attribute.  Unless I missed something, this example does not deal with attributes at all.

Comment: Also, this question is regarding VB.NET.  This example is in C#.

Comment: u may convert it to vb.net